# Can Spring Sleuth be used as distributed logging framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

We want to add a tracer id(MDC) across multiple REST services as part of the logging, so we can follow all calls in our log based on the id.

Is Spring sleuth suitable for using as distributed logging framework with 100% sampling all the time, or are we misusing it?

We are concerned about the overhead with 100% sampling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can modify the percentage at runtime if necessary. We wouldn't be building a tool that is not suitable for distributed systems.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It's because I got the impression that sleuth is mostly used to sample for periodic measurements, and not a framework for also adding a trace id in general for all calls

Comment: Sampling is more about not making zipkin or any other visualization tool blow up.